# Tumblr API followers total

Tags: api, tumblr

I'm trying to get the number of followers on my blog to display on the blogs index page. I currently have the total posts by using this with some JS code:

```
var posts = tumblr_api_read['posts-total'] // total posts
```

But I've tried tweeking it to `total_users` as suggedted in the Tumblr API manual but nothing happens, it says undefined.

Can anyone help.

Answer (score 2):

You can see your total amount of followers by issuing

```
GET
```

on

```
api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/{base-hostname}/followers
```

where base-hostname is your blog's name.
The behavior is documented [here](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2#blog-followers) in the Tumblr API docs. Keep in mind you need to be authenticated with [OAuth](http://www.tumblr.com/oauth/apps) for the request to go through.

The total_users request you read about is actually a response that you get when you issue the followers request. May I ask which API you're using?

Comment: I'm not sure which API I'm using, not very clued up on API. It took me weeks of googling to find out how to do the first one, which uses JSON.